# Comparing an Income vs Growth fund

Tags: mutual-funds, stock-analysis

Looking at FRIFX vs FRESX - the former is an income REIT, the latter a capital growth fund.

Does the view at [Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance?q=FRIFX%20FRESX) compare the performance of both funds assuming all dividends from the income fund are re-invested in the same?

If not, how can one compare the performance of an income vs growth fund?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The graphs are based on price and do not account for dividends to my knowledge. You need to do a deeper dive on the research to find the true return for these funds as you've discovered one of the downfalls of looking at price only.

Comment: Thank you - what would be a valid method for researching/determining "true return"?

Comment: The fund itself should provide a prospectus or annual report by mail to shareholders or online for the rest of us.